# sencha 2: how to show dataview in container

Tags: extjs, containers, store, dataview

I create the dataview in controller, but it cannot be shown as normal.
I am a newer in sencha, need help please.

**app.js**

```
Ext.application({

    name: 'ajmd',
    views: [
        'center'
    ],
    controllers: [
        'center'
    ],
    launch: function() {
        Ext.Viewport.add([{
            xtype:'centerView'
        }]);       
    }
});
```

**center.js**  *(view)*

```
Ext.define("ajmd.view.center", {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'centerView'
});
```

**center.js**  *(controller)*

```
Ext.define("ajmd.controller.center", {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    config: {
        refs:{
            main:'centerView'
        },
        control:{
            main:{
                initialize:'fnInitial'
            }
        }
    },
    fnInitial:function(item){
        var touchTeam = Ext.create('Ext.DataView', {
            // items:[{
            //  xtype:'panel',
            //  html:'hello world'
            // }],
            store: {
                fields: ['name', 'age'],
                data: [
                    {name: 'Jamie Avins',  age: 100},
                    {name: 'Rob Dougan',   age: 21},
                    {name: 'Tommy Maintz', age: 24},
                    {name: 'Jacky Nguyen', age: 24},
                    {name: 'Ed Spencer',   age: 26}
                ]
            },
            itemTpl:'{name} is {age} years old'
        });
        var myPanel = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
            html: 'This will be added to a Container'
        });
        item.add(myPanel);
        item.add(touchTeam);
    }
});
```

**results**

This will be added to a Container

======================================================

if I uncomment those items within dataview, it can only show the items(hello world) in dataview, but the name and age cannot be shown all the time. I cannot figure out what's the problem.

thanks.

Comment: what do you expect to be displayed?

Comment: I just want to show the words in store with dataview.

Answer (score 1):

There is no **Ext.dataview.DataView** component in Ext4.

Try with **Ext.DataView**.

Check the working code at -

http://jsfiddle.net/f9SXF/1/

```
Ext.create('Ext.DataView', {

    // items:[{
    //  xtype:'panel',
    //  html:'hello world'
    // }],
    store: {
        fields: ['name', 'age'],
        data: [
            {name: 'Jamie Avins',  age: 100},
            {name: 'Rob Dougan',   age: 21},
            {name: 'Tommy Maintz', age: 24},
            {name: 'Jacky Nguyen', age: 24},
            {name: 'Ed Spencer',   age: 26}
        ]
    },
    itemTpl:'{name} is {age} years old'
});
```

Comment: thank you for your response. I try Ext.DataView , but nothing changed, the problem does still exist.  And also, these code is used in sencha 2.2.1

Comment: which version of extjs are you using?

Comment: Thank you, I got your code, but I am still not sure what is my problem.

Comment: Actually, I am not sure what's the factor to display the dataview.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Undefined, @Benka.

I figure out the problem by add width and height config.

```
var touchTeam = Ext.create('Ext.DataView', {
            // fullscreen: true,
            // items:[{
            //  xtype:'panel',
            //  html:'hello world'
            // }],
            width:'100%',
            height:'100%',
            store: {
                fields: ['name', 'age'],
                data: [
                    {name: 'Jamie Avins',  age: 100},
                    {name: 'Rob Dougan',   age: 21},
                    {name: 'Tommy Maintz', age: 24},
                    {name: 'Jacky Nguyen', age: 24},
                    {name: 'Ed Spencer',   age: 26}
                ]
            },
            itemTpl:'<div>{name} is {age} years old</div>'
        });
```

I found the data is hidden by the the block of app.css
.x-layout-card{position:relative;overflow:hidden}

actually, the data can be display if x-layout-card is covered by my css, but cannot display on mobile as well. But if I use width and height config, data can be shown in phone and web.

thanks all of you.

It is my first time to ask question here . It's amazing and thank you for your response.

Comment: cool! i'm glad you found the solution. It that works, accept your own answer, so others can learn from this ;)

Answer (score -1):

Remove `,` from the end of `main:'centerView',` here:

```
refs:{
    main:'centerView',
},
```

Comment: that won't be a problem!

Comment: @PrasadK i think it might depend where do you use it. I had a lot of issues with trailing `,` commas. Basically it can break your entire code in Sencha.

Comment: Yeah, commas also create a problem in IE 7 and below browsers. But in his example, he says his code works when he uncomment those commented lines. So, comma would not be a problem in his case. Sorry for commenting in a generic way- :)

Comment: Thanks , but the problem is still there after removed the trail commas.